# Exception "No suitable constructor found for type [simple type..." while parsing XML file to POJO by fasterxml

Tags: java, xml, fasterxml

I need to deserialize some XML file to regular java object using jackson-dataformat-xml. So I'm doing:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
return mapper.readValue(xmlString, Certificate.class);
```

**xmlString** has appearence:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <doc>
        <r  key="0">
            <ATT_SEARCH DM="dm1" DS="ds1" DocType="1"/>
            <ATT_SEARCH DM="dm2" DS="ds2" DocType="2"/>
        </r>
    </doc>
```

And class **Certificate:**

```
package ua.max;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import java.util.List;


@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "doc")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Certificate {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "r")
    private R r;

    public R getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(R r) {
        this.r = r;
    }


    public class R {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ATT_SEARCH")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        private List<AttSearch> attSearch;

        public List<AttSearch> getAttSearch() {
            return attSearch;
        }

        public void setAttSearch(List<AttSearch> attSearch) {
            this.attSearch = attSearch;
        }

        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "key")
        private String key;

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }


        public class AttSearch {

            @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "DM")
            private String dm;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "DS")
            private String ds;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "DocType")
            private String docType;


            public String getDm() {
                return dm;
            }

            public void setDm(String dm) {
                this.dm = dm;
            }

            public String getDs() {
                return ds;
            }

            public void setDs(String ds) {
                this.ds = ds;
            }

            public String getDocType() {
                return docType;
            }

            public void setDocType(String docType) {
                this.docType = docType;
            }


        }


    }


}
```

After trying to deserealize XML, I got the exception:
**"No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ua.max.Certificate$R]: can not instantiate from JSON object"**

My attempts:
1. If I add modifier "static" for my inner classes it's working, I get java object, but except List of 2 object "ATT-SEARCH" I got the first one is null
2. The addition of different constructors did not make any effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R` and `AttSearch` should be static:

```
 public static class R {
   // other stuff

 public static class AttSearch {
   // other stuff
```

Otherwise compiler create default constructor with outer class reference as parameter, so fasterxml can't find constructor without parameters and create pojo.

Comment: If I use "static" my first element of List<AttSearch> is null.

Comment: I have another example (without List elements) where all working good (I can show you if need). That's why I guess that suppose to work without "static", but I dont understand how can I do it. What should I do to fix the problem with constructors?

Comment: I tried your example and there's no null element at `attSearch` field (2 elements). I'm using `fasterxml` with 2.2.2 version.

Comment: If you do't want make this classes static then just move them to package level :)

Comment: I'm using 2.1.3 version - the first object is null, but on the 2.2.2 - I got exception: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BeanPropertyDefinition.getWrapperName()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyName;_        I've already agree on the static :) What exactly you do except adding "static"? Maybe you can share your source?

Comment: About static and non-static classes you can read from [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! With "static" and version 2.2.2. The problem was in multimodule project - dependency from parent component (2.2.2) conflict with dependency in submodule